# Upload BASE64 binary file to SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, base64, binaryfiles

I have been looking for ways to upload BASE64 binary files days and I am stuck.
First of all a do not know how to convert BASE64 binary file to array buffer, blob, ... Everything is about BASE64 string but I have BASE64 binary file.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: BASE64 is a text-encoding of binary data, but what do you mean when talking about a BASE64 binary file? Do you have a BASE64-representation of data and want to upload the binary form? Giving examples of what you intend might help us understand better...

Comment: Oh OK you are right. I have BASE64 encoded binary data (digital signature - .asice file, some kind of zip file) and I want to upload this BASE64 encoded binary data to Sharepoint library as binary file - signature.asice

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert this Base64 string to byte array. C# Programming provide several approaches to do this without trouble. Following [Upload large files sample SharePoint Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint) and [Convert.FromBase64String(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0), both at Microsoft Docs, the final code that meet your requirements will be like this:

```
       //This approach is useful for short files, less than 2Mb:
       public void UploadFileContentFromBase64(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string fileName, string base64Str)
       {
          Web web = ctx.Web;
        
          // Ensure that target library exists. Create if it is missing.
          if (!LibraryExists(ctx, web, libraryName))
          {
            CreateLibrary(ctx, web, libraryName);
          }
        
          FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        
          // The next line of code causes an exception to be thrown for files larger than 2 MB.
          newFile.Content = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);
          newFile.Url = fileName;
        
          // Get instances to the given library.
          List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
        
          // Add file to the library.
          Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
          ctx.Load(uploadFile);
          ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    
    //This other approach provides you to Upload large files, more than 2Mb:
    public void UploadDocumentContentStreamFromBase64(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string fileName, string base64Str)
    {
      Web web = ctx.Web;
      // Ensure that the target library exists. Create it if it is missing.
      if (!LibraryExists(ctx, web, libraryName))
      {
        CreateLibrary(ctx, web, libraryName);
      }
      byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);
      using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent))
      {
        FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    
        // This is the key difference for the first case - using ContentStream property
        flciNewFile.ContentStream = memStream;
        flciNewFile.Url = fileName;
        flciNewFile.Overwrite = true;
    
        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);
    
        ctx.Load(uploadFile);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to stay in javascript (client side).